# How to parse a string and convert it to double based on a format string?

Tags: c#, parsing, double

I'm currently building a custom validation control where I try to parse a string of a number in a double similar to the `DateTime.ParseExact` function.

Here is what I try to archive:

```
Console.WriteLine(Double.ParseExact("12.00", "0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString()); // should print "12"
Console.WriteLine(Double.ParseExact("asd", "0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString()); // should throw FormatException
Console.WriteLine(Double.ParseExact("12.000", "0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString()); // should throw FormatException, because it has to many decimal digits
```

I know I could simply parse it without format string, but I want some stricter rules to apply here. The format string can a [standard format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) or [custom format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx), thus it can be different.

Of course, this method above does not exist. Here is an existing method on the `DateTime` class that does the same, but with `DateTime`s:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2016-09-06T11:57:55.335", "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```

How can I do the same for `Double`?

---

By the way ...

the reason for that is I'm building a custom asp.net webforms `RangeValidator` I inherited from `BaseValidator`. I want to make this control be compatible with `DateTime`, too, and it has to use a custom format string and uses the `InvariantCulture` to make it fully compatible with new HTML5 controls (`[type=numeric]` and `[type=datetime]`).

It would be great the numeric validation part of the control acts similar to the DateTime validation part. Also, if someone enters a wrong string representation of the number, it would be nice to decline the request from the validator.

Comment: Have you looked at Double.TryParse? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @sr28 `Double.TryParse` does not offer me to give a strict format string.

Comment: I think it does..."Converts the string representation of a number in a *specified style* and culture-specific format to its double-precision floating-point number equivalent"

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did not copy the code correctly ... I think this handles the three cases you mentioned...

```
string input = "12.00";

double validationCheck = Convert.ToDouble(input);

string validationCheck1 = validationCheck.ToString("0.00",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

if (input!=validationCheck1) /* Validation Failed */ ;
```

You'll also need to check for exceptions.